# How 95 come to be a prime number in this codeline?

Tags: python, function, while-loop

I've been given an homework to find the prime numbers until a given number and I wrote out that code as answer

```
def count_primes(num):
    primes = [2]
    x = 3
    if num < 2:
        return 0
    while x <= num:
        for y in range(3,x,2):
            if x%y == 0:
                x += 2
        else:
            primes.append(x)
            x += 2
    print(primes)
```

But the problem is when I wrote 100 as num I had got the following out:

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 95, 97, 101]
```

as I saw the 101 in the output I've added `break` command line after 'line 9' that also had me getting rid of 95 as output which is:

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
```

SO how is that `break` line blocked 95 to be a prime number in this code?

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.
Where are you confused?  You've asked a holistic question about your program, but the issue at hand is from the internal logic.  As the posting guidelines tell you, we expect that you've already tried to work through this on your own, but I see no evidence of that in your posting.

Comment: @Prune I've already solved the problem with writing 'break' on line 10 I don't want you to debug my codeline. I'm just asking the logic behind 'break' command to understand why is that happened. Please try to be kinder next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens cause you never reset the y value.
So as 93 is divisible by 31, you increase the value o x by 2.

The next comparison is 95 % 33, it never goes back to 5.

```
def count_primes(num):
    primes = [2]
    x = 3
    if num < 2:
        return 0
    while x <= num:
        for y in range(3, x, 2):
            if x % y == 0:
                x += 2
                break
        else:
            primes.append(x)
            x += 2
    print(primes)
```

Comment: After a few trials on shell I can confirm that, that's the absolute answer I was looking for thank you very much